# Div created from code doesn't load classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div container and inside couple div with class demo and gravity like

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative;width=400px;height=400px;">
<div class="demo gravity" ></div>
<div class="demo gravity"></div>
<div class="demo gravity"></div>
</div>
```

and I add new div from code like

```
    var temp = $('<div/>');
    temp.attr('id', 'foo');
    temp.css( {
        position : 'absolute',
        top : '0px',
        left : '0px',
        width : '200px',
        height : '40px'
    });
    temp.addClass("gravity");
    temp.addClass("demo");
    $('#container').append(temp);
```

in onReady function I have code something  like

```
$(.demo).resizable().draggable().droppable() ;
```

and it works for divs inside but it doesn't work for div which I added from code. Div from code shows inside div with id="container" but is not resizable/draggable/droppable. Does anybody knows what is the problem ?

Comment: Are you after creating div run `$(.demo).resizable().draggable().droppable();` too?

Comment: `$(.demo)` is invalid, try `$('.demo')`

Comment: Not your problem, but just some info: You can combine the two classes together. `temp.addClass("gravity demo")` and you really should use chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here fiddle example for you, seems working.

http://jsfiddle.net/ymutlu/cvZpX/2/

In case deleted fiddle,

```
    var temp = $('<div>');
    temp.append("33");
    temp.attr('id', 'foo');
    temp.css( {
        position : 'absolute',
        top : '0px',
        left : '0px',
        width : '200px',
        height : '40px'
    });​
    temp.addClass("gravity");
    temp.addClass("demo");
    $('#container').append(temp);

var demo = $(".demo");
demo.resizable().draggable().droppable();​
```

//edited after Jamiec comment
you can use

```
temp.resizable().draggable().droppable();​
```

where you add temp divs.

Comment: This is fine if you're adding all your divs in code *before* the call to resizable/draggable/droppable, but fails if any are added dynamically after the page is done loading (ie, added from a button click)

Comment: You are right your solution works fine. temp.resizable().draggable().droppable();​ works also.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're adding the new div *after* the call to `resizable().draggable().droppable()` on all its siblings.

Could you not just add this before appending it (BTW you can chain together all of those calls):

```
    var temp = $('<div/>');
    temp.attr('id', 'foo')
    .css( {
        position : 'absolute',
        top : '0px',
        left : '0px',
        width : '200px',
        height : '40px'
       })
   .addClass("gravity")
   .addClass("demo")
   .resizable().draggable().droppable();
$('#container').append(temp);
```

Here's the jsfiddle demonstrating that newly added divs do in fact work: http://jsfiddle.net/xqakj/

Answer (score 2):

You need to make this for newly created div too:

```
temp.resizable().draggable().droppable();
```